# How to rename a file in Julia?

Tags: julia

I currently have a dataset of images with no folder structure. However, based on the existing image name, I want to rename and move the file to a different folder structure (assuming the folders exist, I can also just make the folder programmatically).

In Python, I can just rename the file and it will move to the updated location I specify. How can I rename a file in Julia?

Comment: It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.234024286.1949022841.1631233456-1690002512.1626695629&_gac=1.118873467.1631243013.Cj0KCQjw4eaJBhDMARIsANhrQAAr9FjQp8hjie7s2gkeOGuC4H9izpdqrerj3VpLe7e9l0cnTHr_1bsaAmPYEALw_wcB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Julia's base filesystem, there is an `mv` command which you can use to move and rename the file as follows:

```
julia> write("hello.txt", "world"); # here we create a text file.

julia> mv("hello.txt", "goodbye.txt") # we then move it, but the file stays in the same dir so it is just renamed from hello to goodbye.
"goodbye.txt"

julia> mv("goodbye.txt", "./test/hello.txt") # in this example, we actually move the file from the existing folder into a new test folder as well as change the name.
"./test/hello.txt"

julia>
```

You can read more about the [`mv` function in the Julia docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.mv).

Comment: There is no need to add the `./` in the `./test/hello.txt`. It can just be `test/hello.txt`.